# Good software/module in python to determine nuclear attraction integral in Slater type orbital basis sets

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, numerical-analysis

I am trying to solve a Hamiltonian of one electron and 10 stationary nuclear centers. here, the electron is treated quantum mechanically and nuclear centers are treated classically objects. The Hamilton is as follows,
$$H=-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{R_{i}}|}$$. Charge on each nuclear center is one. For the given set of locations of nuclear centers I tried to solve the Hamiltonian using MO theory by mixing  $1s$, $2px$,$2py$,$2pz$ of all the 10 centers making a total basis of 40 with arbitrary coefficients to be determined.

Now I have used STO -3G to compute the one electron attraction integral by using the existing algorithm and wrote my own code. My question is whether there any software package to compute all the integrals (one electron integral) using slater type orbital in python. Because STO-3G is not an accurate representation of slater type orbital. Do I need to go for FORTRAN for slater type orbital basis set calculations?

Also is there any reference books or papers where I can find the algorithm for slater type orbitals one-electron integrals?

Comment: I would argue that in order to get accurate results, using several GTOs on each center will probably get you farther than one fixed STO. Nonetheless, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum_chemistry_and_solid_state_physics_software lists DFTB+ as having STOs. The integral code is likely to be Fortran still.

Comment: Thank you so much.What GTO basis set would be appropriate for the above Hamiltonian. I already used STO-3G to solve the above Hamiltonian. How do I verify my answers? and how do I know how much, the answers are deviating from the right answers? @TAR86

Comment: Any sufficiently sized basis set will do, check https://bse.pnl.gov/bse/portal for candidates. Given that you have a single electron, Hartree-Fock is exact in the given basis set. You could run your calculation in e.g. ORCA to verify your code. To assess the quality of the solution, observe the rate of convergence when using subsequently larger sets, such as cc-pVXZ, where X = D, T, Q, 5 ...

Comment: @TAR86. Thank you so much again. Is there any better references or lecture notes or any review articles about theoretical chemistry which has all the pieces of information you said about Hartree Fock

Comment: I learned from Wikipedia that ORCA is supported only in C++. Do we have a similar software package in python to verify the answers and observe the rate of convergence @TAR86

Comment: The write-up on wikipedia is not entirely bad, for detailed derivation and mathematics have a look at Szabo, mentioned on wiki. ORCA is closed source, but would do all that I think you try to do here. The point is that HF is the same and exact for one electron in any quantum chemistry package - so why program it (unless that's the point).

Comment: I am completely new to Quantum chemistry. Thank you so much for explaining patiently. All I need is the eigenfunctions of the above mentioned Hamiltonian. If I get it from ORCA, then that is fine. Thank you so much once again. Please suggest some good reference or tutorials about ORCA@TAR86

Comment: There is a google site: https://sites.google.com/site/orcainputlibrary/home and the manual is not bad (I wrote parts of it). You would set up a "molecule" consisting of 10 hydrogen, multiplicity 2, charge +9. Choose HF, a basis set and let it rip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90161/discussion-between-user135580-and-tar86).

Comment: Thanks sir, In this software, is it possible to get excited states for the above Hamiltonian ? Does this give a all the excited states of this Hamiltonian mentioned above ?@TAR86